# Is it safe to use Tomcat CSRF filter which exposes token in the URL?

Tags: tomcat, csrf-protection

Tomcat supports a CSRF filter that appends a token to the URL.  Doesn't this expose the token?  It seems like this is not a secure solution.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

A CSRF attack does not intercept traffic from server to client. It piggybacks on credentials on the client and sends a message to the server.

Normal Use of the CSRF TOken:

1. The server generates a CSRF token and sends it to the client.
2. The client receives the CSRF token as part of the URL (NOT as a cookie/param!).
3. The client sends a request with the CSRF back.

In a CSRF attack:

1. The attacker generates a forged request in a forged website. This does not have a CSRF key attached to it.
2. The client initiates the forged request through the forged website.
3. The request fails at the server as the CSRF key is not known by the attacker and not provided the request.

The attacker in a CSRF attack should never be intercepting requests/responses, only forging a response from an external site. If it is intercepting the CSRF key, then the attack is not a cross-site forgery, as the attacker is now a man-in-the-middle.

We shouldn't worry if an intermediary can see the CSRF token, because it's not designed to stop intermediary attacks.